# jquery getJSON failing with valid result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am calling a REST web service using jQuery 1.9.1 and returning JSON.

My code is:

```
  var jqxhr = $.getJSON( LoginUrl, function() {
        console.log( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
      console.log( "error" );
  });
```

On the server side, I have implemented CORS as directed here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

I have sniffed the connection using rawcap for my localhost windows box and everything looks fine on the HTTP packets going back and forth. When I look at my console it says the http request returned 200.

The problem is that it always calls the fail() method and dumps error in the console log.

I've spent a full day studying google and wikipedia and debugging the javascript and I still seem to be missing something.

Comment: Why don't you try logging the actual error provided by jQuery? How sure are you that the response is actually valid JSON?

Comment: @nnnnnn I think the validity of the json does not matter here. Probably the CORS directive is not set correctly. you could as well try to set crossDomain to true (although this already should be the case). I experienced getting a 200 but silently failing due to SOP.

Comment: crossDomain is set to true. The JSON is irrelevant because I just replaced the getJSON with a regular get and it's behaving the same way.

Comment: Do you see any *other* errors in your console?  Also, `.fail()` passes you some parameters, log *those* and not just `'error'`: `.fail(function(jqXHR, status, error){ console.log(status, error); });`.